# What is the purpose of the directory Packages in my Assets directory?

Tags: unity

So far I used EditorWindow script but few minutes ago without and alert I have strange stuff in the Assets in the Editor.
I see now a new folder name Packages I can't figure out where it came from but for 100% I didn't import any packages at all.

Second when I put the mouse on it and right click I can't delete it:

[image: Packages]

This is how the Packages looks like, Very strange thing:

[image: Packages]

Another strange thing but maybe it's connected to this Packages is that in the Scene view window I have this blue thing like a line or something that if I click on it it will be blue if not clicking on it it's black. Not sure what it is. It's not an object in the Hierarchy. Not sure where it came from.

I tried to restart the Unity over again but nothing same strange stuff.

[image: Strange line in scene view]

I'm using unity3d 2018.2.5f1 Personal. And windows 10 home 64bit version 1803.

I see the Packages folder on the Hard disk now but when I make double click to get inside I see only one small file: manifest.json

And I was working and working with json file format to save and load but I can't figure out what is going on in the scene view and in the assets.

Comment: I tried to delete the Packages folder from the hard disk but then when back to the editor I keep see the Packages in the Assets and then I see the folder again in the hard disk too but again in the hard disk it have one small file but in the editor under Packages I see a lot of stuff including many scripts. What is going on here ?

Comment: If anyone else got this thing please add a comment please.

Comment: It might help to also include your operating system.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the new Package Manager, available in Unity 2018, stores installed packages. You can read up on it here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@1.8/manual/index.html

Comment: Ok I saw it now. I could remove almost all the packages but the Package Manager UI 1.9.11 can't be remove and also the Packages it self can't be remove. And still I have this strange blue think in the scene view I can click on it but it's not an object.

Comment: That seems unrelated

Comment: This is part of the Unity engine now. You probably don't want to be deleting from that folder. The packages in your screenshot are standard Unity assets. They're not necessarily being used in your project.

Comment: @jdoedoedoedoe You can't delete this folder for the same reason you can't delete the Assets folder: Unity needs it.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's one mistake made in this situation:

The *Package* folder is not in the *Asset* folder, but in the project's root.

This was a small change done to Unity since the 2018 version to allow the engine editor to be more versatile and autonomous when it comes to third party plugins and packages imported into a project. Prior to 2018, most of the things you find in the Packages were either automatically included by default (even if not used) in every Unity builds, or had to be imported in the Editor folder that was outside of the Asset folder.

In the Packages folder, the engine automatically add some "default" packages such as Unity UI, Analytics Library, Unity Ads, etc. The importance of each folder is based on what you need in your project.

Should you erase all of them? While it's possible to erase 99% of them, I suggest you first take a look at each Packages' names. For example, if you use the Unity Colalborate feature (multiple developers working from different station), you need to keep the "Unity Colalborate" package. If you're not using the Legacy UI, but an actual in-scene canvas for the UI/Interaction/buttons, you got to keep the "Unity UI" package. If you plan on having some Advertisement in your game (like on Mobile) and want a relatively quick & easy setup for fetching the ads, the "com.unity.ads" includes some really versatile tools. If you plan on having in-App purchase, there's a default package for that too.

One of the reason why this change was done to the Engine is also to allow a better flow with Unity's Asset Store. Prior to this change, when you bought a plugin in the Asset Store that was supposed to be located in the Editor folder (so that the in-editor tools could be displayed), you had to manually move files around which was a real Q&A issue as someone making a mistake could ended up breaking a project. With the addition of the "Packages" folder, not only is it possible for the Asset Store to add all the Editor & Assets of a plugin into the project folder, but it's also possible to update all those files without any user interaction (other than starting the update from the Asset Store).

If you want to remove those folders, at least I suggest you first do it through the Package Manager (Window/Package Manager). This menu explains what each package does and has a cool little "Remove" button that ensure each package are properly removed. (In the Packages Manager, the installed packages have a checkmark on the right of their version number. Those without a checkmark are available, but not installed in the current project).